# How to plot value of loss function in time

Tags: tensors, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Am working with linear regression
$$\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ ... \\ y_n \end{bmatrix} \approx \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & ... & x_{1n} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} & ... & x_{2n} \\ .. & .. & ... \\ x_{m1} & x_{m2} & ... & x_{mn} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ ... \\ a_n \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ ... \\ b_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
My loss function is:

$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (y_i -  (x_{ij} a_j +bj)  )^2$$

This function return vector consisting of j elements. In my gradient descent algorithm each iteration I call the norm of the vector returned by the loss function. And then to show that I minimize the loss function I plot number of iterations and value of norm for a given iteration. This is a good idea or there is there a better way to show minimalization of loss function?

Quick look

```
loss_arr = []

def grad_des_lin(y,x,w,bias,step,epos):
    for u in range(epos):
        # minimalize bias and w
        # .....
        # and then calculated loss for this iteration
        loss_arr.append(np.linalg.norm(los_fun(y,x,w,bias)))  

grad_des_lin(y,x,w,bias,step,epos)

plt.plot(range(epos), loss_arr)
```

Comment: the parameter step of the function grad_des_lin isn't used.

Comment: It's used, but I didn.t show it. It's used in part ```#minimalize bias and w```. I didn't wanna show extra code if it's not necessary.

Comment: The loss function whose formula you have given in the question yields a scalar. There must be a bug in your code if you are computing a vector instead.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to compute the norm of your loss function for a particular couple of input/output $(x,y)$. Rather, you should compute the mean of these norms on a set $S$ of input/output couples.

I suggest that you take $S$ to be a (fixed) randomly selected subset of your training data. After each step, you can append mean_los_fun(S,w,bias) to loss_arr, here's a possible definition of mean_los_fun(S,w,bias) :

```
def mean_los_fun(S,w,bias):
   return np.mean([np.linalg.norm(los_fun(y,x,w,bias)) for (x,y) in S])
```